# PyQt, PyQtGraph signal error in small amount of code

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph, pyqt6

I am just starting out with PyQtGraph but when I try to add a graph using the following code:

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(pg.PlotWidget(), 0, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(800, 600)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabe\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsObject.py", line 24, in itemChange
    self.parentChanged()
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabe\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ViewBox\ViewBox.py", line 57, in itemChange
    ret = ItemGroup.itemChange(self, change, value)
  File "C:\Users\Gabe\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\GraphicsObject.py", line 24, in itemChange
    self.parentChanged()
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

I am very confused because the code seems very simple and I am not sure where an issue could possibly be. I am using python3 to run it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, it's a recent bug related to the latest version of PySide6.2.2. See [issue #2152](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/2152) and #2132. It will be fixed in the next release of pyqtgraph and/or Qt. In the meantime you could consider downgrading to a previous version of PySide or try with PyQt instead (remember: you cannot use PySide *and* PyQt together, you use one or the other).

Comment: Want to make this an answer so I can close this question?

Comment: I cannot test it, so I cannot know if or when it will be actually fixed. I'd suggest you to wait until it's fixed and check it for yourself, and in the meantime the comment would suffice.

Comment: FYI: it was fixed and merged into master in PR #2132 on Dec 9, 2021: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/pull/2132 I tested it recently...of course, that's only good if OP is comfortable with using latest pre-release code.